# Delphi 2007 not restoring tabs when opening a project

Tags: delphi, project

I have a new install of Delphi 2007 on Win 7 Pro...

When I open a project file, the files (tabs) that were open when I last closed the project are not restored (the files are not re-opened).

What am I missing, to get it to restore the tabs? (The last time I installed D 2007 was a couple years ago.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn on the option to save the project desktop, in **Tools->Options->Environment Options**. It's the **AutoSave Options** checkbox for **Project desktop**.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Wasn't aware of that for years. Breakpoints are also saved.

Comment: Thanks Ken. None of the words and phrases I Googled or searched for in Help could get me there! Odd how that works (or fails to) at times.